# How to create a python package with multiple files without subpackages

Tags: python, python-module

I am attempting to create a package (mypackage) that contains a few classes, but would like the classes contained in multiple files.

For example, I want class_a.py to contain a class named ClassA, etc...

Thus, I would like the following file structure:

```
  .../mypackage 
       __init__.py
       class_a.py
       class_b.py
       ...
```

However, I would like to load and use the package as follows:

```
load mypackage
a = mypackage.ClassA()
```

What do I need to do (I assume in the __init__.py) file to make this possible. Currently, it operates using "mypackage.class_a.ClassA()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `__init__.py` import all your `ClassA`, `ClassB`, etc from other files.

Then you'll be able to `import mypackage` and use `mypackage.ClassA`, or `from mypackage import ClassA` and use it as unqualified `ClassA`.

A bit of background.

An `import foo` statement looks for `foo.py`, then for `foo/__init__.py`, and loads the names defined in that file into the current namespace. Put whatever you need to be "top-level" into `__init__.py`.

Also, [take a look at `__all__` top-level variable](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) if you tend to `from mypackage import *`.

Comment: Or better yet, never ever use `from mypackage import *`, ever, under any circumstances.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I agree because it's quite annoying when you go through some code looking where you defined something, but then you realize it came with the package that you imported.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, in your `__init__.py` for a class, use the following:

```
from class_a import ClassA
from class_b import ClassB
```

for the case of a file without a class, use the following:

```
from . import file_a
from . import file_b
```

or if you only want to expose specific methods of a file:

```
from .file_a import method_a
from .file_b import method_b
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `__init__.py`, add this:

```
from class_a import ClassA
from class_b import ClassB

del class_a
del class_b
```

Comment: Really the name `class_a` won't be defined, and `del` will fail.