# Very basic Python project structure fails

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have the following project:

```
apack/
  apack/
    __init__.py
    apack.py
    aux.py
  setup.py
```

`apack.py`:

```
def foo(x):
    return x
```

`aux.py`:

```
from apack import foo

def bar():
    return foo() + 1
```

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='apack',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

I install the package with `pip install .`. However, the result is a an empty package:

```
>>> import apack
>>> apack.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'apack' has no attribute 'foo'
```

What I would like to have is:

```
>>> import apack
>>> apack.foo()
>>> apack.bar()
```

There is a number of similar questions here (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353218/installed-module-is-empty), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425434/how-to-create-a-python-package-with-multiple-files-without-subpackages)). However, none of them is minimal enough for me to understand why my example does not work.

Answer (score 2):

When you import the package it invokes the `__init__` file of the package. You can confirm this in your python interpreter.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.__file__
'<PATH>\\lib\\json\\__init__.py'
```

So to have `foo` and `bar` available from your package level you have to import `foo` and `bar` into the `__init__` file of your package. ie,

```
from .apack import foo
from .aux import bar
```

Comment: To add: and subsequently, in `aux.py` instead of `from apack import foo`, import relatively: `from .apack import foo`.

Comment: @Felipe Why? What I currently have seems to work.

Comment: @Felipe There is this excerpt from PEP https://stackoverflow.com/a/12738912/1398282. However, the explanation involves a series of vaguenesses such as "a module inside a package can't easily import itself ". Why would a module ever import itself? A module always has access to its own namespace, what do I get by importing a module to itself?

Comment: Regarding the relative import - honestly, before your question (and my subsequent research thereafter) I always thought it was recommended. It seems [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) actually recommends the opposite -- absolute over relative imports. Regarding the last comment, I believe they mean that relative import allows you to import the module in-itself. In other-words, inside `aux.py` you can do `from . import aux`. The only reason why I could see one wanting to do this is to specify the module for every func/objs/declarable inside the module's namespace.

Comment: Imagine `aux.py` importing `foo.bar()` and having a `bar()` function inside of it. Doing `from . import aux` inside `aux.py` will allow you to use the `bar()` function as `foo.bar()` and `aux.bar()`, differentiating both. Again - my only thoughts as to _why_ this would be useful. I've never encountered this in the wild myself.